# Aligning two elements to the bottom inside a column

Tags: html, css

I have a row split in 4 columns on a footer section, in the last column to the right I want to add something like the picture attached, but I want to preserve the look of the image and text together along all screens sizes, with what I have only works for smaller screens, and the wider the screen gets, the image and the text separate each other apart too much. How can I achieve this?

[image]

```css
.wrapper {
  position:relative;
  text-align:center;
  margin:0 auto;
}

.footer {
  font-size:40px;
  color:black;
}
.talk {
  position:absolute;
  text-align:left;
  bottom:0;
}

.footer-logo {
  vertical-align: bottom;
  float:right;
  height:150px !important;
}
```

```html
 <div class="wrapper">
    <p class="footer talk">Big Text</p>
    <img class="footer-logo" src='http://via.placeholder.com/140x100'>
 </div>
```

Comment: what if my mobile is 340px width? You cannot make such assumptions without clarifying the worst-case scenario - and most importantly what you mean by "*preserved*".

Comment: The text and the image will get smaller if screen size is smaller too, I just want to preserve the image to the right and the text on the left, with about only 10px separation. What it happens now is that they separate each other too much

Comment: You'll need JS to calculate the available space, the number of characters and how they best fit to keep the image in ratio..., than make the caracters... wait, why not just use a single image? What's the gain of having `BigBla [  ]` as text + image and the need to make both of them automagically responsive?..

Answer (score 1):

> you can simply set the `display` of 'image' and the 'text' element to :`inline`

or chage the < p > tag to < span >,

because < p > tag takes the whole line and they couldn't take place together!

but < span > tag is an inline element which takes the content width (and not the screen width)

[here](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_display_visibility.asp) is a useful explanation about "display" property.

```css
.wrapper {
    display: block;
    position:absolute;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
    text-align:center;
    margin:0 auto;
}

.footer {
    display: inline;
}

.talk{
    font-size:40px;
    color:black;
}
.logo{
    height: 150px;
    width: auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
</head>
<body>

<div class="wrapper">
    <span class="footer talk">Big Text</span>
    <img class="footer logo" src='http://via.placeholder.com/140x100'>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try This Code. 
I'am add some  media queries and some div to in html page

Html

```
<div class="wrapper">
   One Columns
 </div>
 <div class="wrapper">
    two Columns
 </div>
  <div class="wrapper">
    three Columns
 </div>
  <div class="wrapper">
  <div class="A">
   <p class="footer talk">Big Text</p>
    <img class="footer-logo" src='http://via.placeholder.com/140x100'>
  </div>

 </div>
```

CSS

```
.wrapper {
  position:relative;
  text-align:center;
  margin:0 auto;
width:25%;
float:left;
}

.footer {
  font-size:40px;
  color:black;
}
.talk {
  position:absolute;
  text-align:left;
  width:50%;
  float:left;
}

.footer-logo {
  vertical-align: bottom;
  float:right;
  height:150px !important;
  width:50%;
  float:right;
}

.A{
  width:100%;
}

@media (max-width:525px){
.A{
  width:100%;
}

.footer-logo {

  width:20%;
  float:right;
}

.talk {

width:20%;
float:left;
font-size:28px;
}
}
```